# Spritekit SKNode size as a percentage

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, size, sprite

I'm trying to add a touch zone to a scene in SpriteKit. It's transparent but needs to match a certain size depending on the size of the device (iPhone 5, 6 , 6+). I've found that if I want to make sure the touchable zone stays the same position and the touchable zone size scales depending on the device, I need to set the position/size as a portion of the scene size. When I use:

```
import SpriteKit
import AVFoundation

class Page1: SKScene {

// MARK: Constant Variables (buttons/background)

let background = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "s2.png")
let menuButton = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "menuButton.png")
let pageForward = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "pageForward.png")
let pageBack = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "pageBack.png")
let soundButton = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "soundButton.png")
let pressSoundButton = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "pressedSoundButton.png")
let pressMenuButton = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "pressedMenuButton.png")
let pressPageForward = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "pressedPageForward.png")
let pressPageBack = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "pressedPageBack.png")

//MARK: Temporary variables

var pageCount = 1
var narrationPlayer: AVAudioPlayer!
var backgroundPlayer: AVAudioPlayer!
var buttonPress: AVAudioPlayer!

//MARK: Nodes

var kittyNode = SKSpriteNode(color: SKColor.redColor(), size: CGSizeMake(100, 100))
var kittyLabel = "Kitty"
var pepperNode = SKSpriteNode(color: SKColor.yellowColor(), size: CGSizeMake(100, 100))
var pepperLabel = "Pepper"
var groundNode = SKSpriteNode(color: SKColor.brownColor(), size: CGSizeMake(100, 100))
var groundLabel = "The ground"
var bushNode = SKSpriteNode(color: SKColor.greenColor(), size: CGSizeMake(100, 100))
var bushLabel = "The bushes"
var racoonNode = SKSpriteNode(color: SKColor.brownColor(), size: CGSizeMake(100, 100))
var racoonLabel = "Racoon"
var forestNode = SKSpriteNode(color: SKColor.whiteColor(), size: CGSizeMake(100, 100))
var forestLabel = "The forest"

// MARK: Initialized classes

var settings = Settings()
var page = PauseMenu()

// MARK: Main code

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    println("In Page1.swift")

    //narration location
    let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("BATCAT01", withExtension: "mp3")
    narrationPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: path, error: nil)

    playBackground()
    playNarration()

    //addming background and default buttons

    background.position = CGPoint(x: size.width/2, y: size.height/2)
    background.size.height = self.size.height/1
    background.size.width = self.size.width/1
    addChild(background)

    menuButton.position = CGPoint(x: size.width-60, y: 60)
    menuButton.size.height = menuButton.size.height/5
    menuButton.size.width = menuButton.size.width/5
    menuButton.alpha = 0.7
    menuButton.zPosition = 10
    addChild(menuButton)

    soundButton.position = CGPoint(x: 60, y: 60)
    soundButton.size.height = soundButton.size.height/5
    soundButton.size.width = soundButton.size.width/5
    soundButton.alpha = 0.7
    soundButton.zPosition = 10
    addChild(soundButton)

    pageForward.position = CGPoint(x: size.width-60, y: size.height-60)
    pageForward.size.height = pageForward.size.height/5
    pageForward.size.width = pageForward.size.width/5
    pageForward.alpha = 0.7
    pageForward.zPosition = 10
    addChild(pageForward)

    pageBack.position = CGPoint(x: 60, y: size.height-60)
    pageBack.size.height = pageBack.size.height/5
    pageBack.size.width = pageBack.size.width/5
    pageBack.alpha = 0.7
    pageBack.zPosition = 10
    //addChild(pageBack)

    //adding pressed buttons and setting alpha

    pressSoundButton.position = CGPoint(x: 60, y: 60)
    pressSoundButton.size.height = pressSoundButton.size.height/5
    pressSoundButton.size.width = pressSoundButton.size.width/5
    pressSoundButton.alpha = 0
    pressSoundButton.zPosition = 11
    addChild(pressSoundButton)

    pressMenuButton.position = CGPoint(x: size.width-60, y: 60)
    pressMenuButton.size.height = pressMenuButton.size.height/5
    pressMenuButton.size.width = pressMenuButton.size.width/5
    pressMenuButton.alpha = 0
    pressMenuButton.zPosition = 11
    addChild(pressMenuButton)

    pressPageForward.position = CGPoint(x: size.width-60, y: size.height-60)
    pressPageForward.size.height = pressPageForward.size.height/5
    pressPageForward.size.width = pressPageForward.size.width/5
    pressPageForward.alpha = 0
    pressPageForward.zPosition = 11
    addChild(pressPageForward)

    pressPageBack.position = CGPoint(x: 60, y: size.height-60)
    pressPageBack.size.height = pressPageBack.size.height/5
    pressPageBack.size.width = pressPageBack.size.width/5
    pressPageBack.alpha = 0
    pressPageBack.zPosition = 11
    //addChild(pressPageBack)

    if settings.checkDimension() == 1 {

        println("Setting up the iPhone touchables")

        kittyNode.zPosition = 11
        kittyNode.alpha = 0.5
        kittyNode.position = CGPoint(x: background.size.width*0.36, y: background.size.height/2) // (155,207) (245,130)
        addChild(kittyNode)

        pepperNode.zPosition = 11
        pepperNode.alpha = 0.5
        pepperNode.position = CGPoint(x: background.size.width*0.61, y: background.size.height*0.32) // (296.0,163.5) (398.5,43.0)
        addChild(pepperNode)

        racoonNode.zPosition = 11
        racoonNode.alpha = 0.5
        racoonNode.position = CGPoint(x: background.size.width*0.84, y: background.size.height*0.535) // (437.0,206.0) (518.0,137.0)
        addChild(racoonNode)

        groundNode.zPosition = 11
        groundNode.alpha = 0.5
        groundNode.position = CGPoint(x: background.size.width/2, y: background.size.height*0.0937) // (1.5,59.5)
        addChild(groundNode)

        bushNode.zPosition = 11
        bushNode.alpha = 0.5
        bushNode.position = CGPoint(x: background.size.width/2, y: background.size.height*0.32) // (1.0,145.5) (568,59.5)
        addChild(bushNode)

        forestNode.zPosition = 11
        forestNode.alpha = 0.5
        forestNode.position = CGPoint(x: background.size.width/2, y: background.size.height*0.727) // (0, 320) (1.0,145.5)
        addChild(forestNode)


    } else if settings.checkDimension() == 2 {

        println("Setting up the iPad touchables")

        //add label nodes
        kittyNode.zPosition = 11
        kittyNode.alpha = 0
        kittyNode.position = CGPoint(x: 360, y: 404.5)
        addChild(kittyNode)

        pepperNode.zPosition = 11
        pepperNode.alpha = 0
        pepperNode.position = CGPoint(x: 627, y: 240)
        addChild(pepperNode)

        groundNode.zPosition = 11
        groundNode.alpha = 0
        groundNode.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width/2, y: 78.5)
        addChild(groundNode)

        bushNode.zPosition = 11
        bushNode.alpha = 0
        bushNode.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width/2, y: 261)
        addChild(bushNode)

        racoonNode.zPosition = 11
        racoonNode.alpha = 0
        racoonNode.position = CGPoint(x: 846, y: 413)
        addChild(racoonNode)

        forestNode.zPosition = 11
        forestNode.alpha = 0
        forestNode.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width/2, y: 564)
        addChild(forestNode)
    }
}

// MARK: Touch handling

override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    /* Called when a touch begins */

    for touch: AnyObject in touches {
        var location = touch.locationInNode(self)
        println("\(location)")

        //checks if someone touched the menu button
        if menuButton.containsPoint(location) {
            println("Play story with sound!")
            menuButton.alpha = 0
            pressMenuButton.alpha = 0.7
            settings.setInProgress()
        }

        if soundButton.containsPoint(location) {
            println("Play story with sound!")
            soundButton.alpha = 0
            pressSoundButton.alpha = 0.7
            settings.setInProgress()
        }

        //checks if someone touched the forward button
        if pageForward.containsPoint(location) {
            println("Next Page!")
            pageForward.alpha = 0
            pressPageForward.alpha = 0.7
            settings.setInProgress()
        }

        if pageBack.containsPoint(location) {
            println("Next Page!")
            pageBack.alpha = 0
            pressPageBack.alpha = 0.7
            settings.setInProgress()
        }
    }
}

//MARK: functions when touches end

override func touchesEnded(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    for touch:AnyObject in touches {
        var location = touch.locationInNode(self)
        println("touch ended at \(location)")

        //user touch error checking
        soundButton.alpha = 0.7
        pressSoundButton.alpha = 0
        menuButton.alpha = 0.7
        pressMenuButton.alpha = 0
        pageForward.alpha = 0.7
        pressPageForward.alpha = 0
        pageBack.alpha = 0.7
        pressPageBack.alpha = 0

        if soundButton.containsPoint(location) { //button code starts
            println("touch ended in sound button")
            soundButton.alpha = 0.7
            pressSoundButton.alpha = 0
            playNarration()
        } else if menuButton.containsPoint(location) {
            println("touch ended in menuButton")
            menuButton.alpha = 0.7
            pressMenuButton.alpha = 0
            goToPauseMenu()
        } else if pageForward.containsPoint(location) {
            println("touch ended in sound button")
            pageForward.alpha = 0.7
            pressPageForward.alpha = 0
            nextPage()
        } else if pageBack.containsPoint(location) {
            println("touch ended in page back button")
            pageBack.alpha = 0.7
            pressPageBack.alpha = 0
            //lastPage()
        } else if kittyNode.containsPoint(location) { //label code starts
            labelActions(kittyLabel, target: location)
        } else if pepperNode.containsPoint(location) {
            labelActions(pepperLabel, target: location)
        } else if groundNode.containsPoint(location) {
            labelActions(groundLabel, target: location)
        } else if bushNode.containsPoint(location) {
            labelActions(bushLabel, target: location)
        } else if racoonNode.containsPoint(location) {
            labelActions(racoonLabel, target: location)
        } else if forestNode.containsPoint(location) {
            labelActions(forestLabel, target: location)
        }
    }
}

// MARK: Button actions

func playNarration() {
    //narration location
    let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("BATCAT01", withExtension: "mp3")
    narrationPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: path, error: nil)
    narrationPlayer.stop()
    narrationPlayer.prepareToPlay()
    narrationPlayer.play()
}

func playBackground() {
    //background location
    let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("BatKitty_Innocence.v1", withExtension: "wav")
    backgroundPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: path, error: nil)
    backgroundPlayer.stop()
    backgroundPlayer.prepareToPlay()
    backgroundPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1
    backgroundPlayer.play()
}

func goToPauseMenu() {
    var scene = PauseMenu(size: self.size)
    page.setPage(pageCount)
    let skView = self.view as SKView!
    skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
    scene.scaleMode = .ResizeFill
    scene.size = skView.bounds.size
    let sceneTransition = SKTransition.revealWithDirection(SKTransitionDirection.Up, duration: 1.3)
    skView.presentScene(scene, transition: sceneTransition)

    let effectPath = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("Soft Pulsing Accent", withExtension: "mp3")
    buttonPress = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: effectPath, error: nil)
    buttonPress.prepareToPlay()
    buttonPress.play()
}

func nextPage() {
    narrationPlayer.stop()
    var scene = Page2(size: self.size)
    let skView = self.view as SKView!
    skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
    scene.scaleMode = .ResizeFill
    scene.size = skView.bounds.size
    let sceneTransition = SKTransition.revealWithDirection(SKTransitionDirection.Left, duration: 1.3)
    skView.presentScene(scene, transition: sceneTransition)

    let effectPath = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("Soft Pulsing Accent", withExtension: "mp3")
    buttonPress = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: effectPath, error: nil)
    buttonPress.prepareToPlay()
    buttonPress.play()
}

func lastPage() {
    var scene = Page1(size: self.size)
    let skView = self.view as SKView!
    skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
    scene.scaleMode = .ResizeFill
    scene.size = skView.bounds.size
    let sceneTransition = SKTransition.revealWithDirection(SKTransitionDirection.Right, duration: 1.3)
    skView.presentScene(scene, transition: sceneTransition)

    let effectPath = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("Soft Pulsing Accent", withExtension: "mp3")
    buttonPress = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: effectPath, error: nil)
    buttonPress.prepareToPlay()
    buttonPress.play()
}

//MARK: Label Triggers

func labelActions(text:String, target:CGPoint) {

    var dice = arc4random_uniform(4)
    var tempText = SKLabelNode(text: text)
    tempText.fontName = "ChalkboardSE-Bold"
    tempText.fontColor = SKColor(red: 0, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1)
    var tempTarget = target

    switch dice {
    case 0:
        println("dice rolled a 0")
        tempText.zRotation = 0.3
    case 1:
        tempText.zRotation = -0.3
        println("dice rolled a 1")
    case 2:
        tempText.zRotation = 0.15
        println("dice rolled a 2")
    case 3:
        tempText.zRotation = -0.15
        println("dice rolled a 3")
    default:
        println("default angle")
    }
    tempText.position = target
    var actions = [SKAction.scaleTo(2, duration: 0.5),
                   SKAction.waitForDuration(3),
                   SKAction.scaleTo(0, duration: 0.5),
                   SKAction.removeFromParent()]
    tempText.runAction(SKAction.sequence(actions))

    addChild(tempText)
}
```

}

Ideally I'd like to set the width to self.size.width*0.25. So if the device width is 100, then the node width would be 25. When I do this it doesn't work though. I get the error **Page1 -> 0 -> Page1!' does not have a member named ' size**

Anyone have any ideas what's going wrong and how I can fix this?

Comment: Your problem is that you can't access self.size sometimes ? Have you tried with self.frame.size ?

Comment: Hello, thanks for answering. When I enter that, I get Page1 -> 0 -> Page1!' does not have a member named ' frame

Comment: `Page1 -> 0 -> Page1!` is an error message ? Does it appear when you write your line or at execution ? Can you provide us a more detailed code and a more detailed error log if available ? You can edit your question to add those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to access the `frame` of your scene. You can do that by using `self.frame.size`. For example:

```
var width:CGFloat = self.frame.size.width/4
var height:CGFloat = self.frame.size.height/4
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for answering. When I enter that, I get Page1 -> 0 -> Page1!' does not have a member named ' frame

Comment: But you are trying to set it inside a function? And you subclass 'SKScene'?

Comment: Hi I edited the post to include more code. let me know if that helps.

Comment: Maybe an dumb question but do you close the method and the class?

Comment: Hi, yea sorry I did. the code is long and I didn't want to post it all

Comment: But you tried my code with self.frame.size.width instead of just size.width right?

Comment: Here. I'll post the entire page

Comment: You need to remove every: self.size and change it to self.frame.size.